# Did not work out creating a DCB in SetCommState

Tags: c++, serial-port, printers

I am programming a GTP-180 receipt printer in c ++, but I have an error while creating a DCB

i took the code from here
http://members.ee.net/brey/Serial.pdf

```
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <IOSTREAM>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void WriteComPort(CString PortSpecifier, CString data)
{
    HANDLE hSerial;
    DWORD byteswritten;

    hSerial = CreateFile(CString("COM5"),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0);

    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_110;
    dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);
    WriteFile(hSerial, data, 1, &byteswritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
}

int main()
{
    WriteComPort("COM5", "\\x1b\\x69");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `GetLastError ()` return after `SetCommState` fails?  Also, is `CBR_110` a valid baud rate for your device?

Comment: I checked through if the error. I deliberately set the lowest speed, I thought there was nothing to worry about.

Comment: The reference article seems to have GetCommState after CreateFile, have you tried it? At the same time, is the DCBlength at the beginning of the DCB set correctly?